# How to upload image from React to ExpressJS and saving it in MongoDB using Express Routes

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

ReactJS

```
const handleChange = async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        setFile(fileReader.result);

    });

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('files', event.target.files[0]);
    data.append('files', file);

    try {
        const postData = { data }

        axios.post("http:localhost:4000/api/user/avatar", data)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
        // const response = await axiosReq('post', 'user/update', postData)
        await getCurrentUser();


    } catch (errors) {
        console.log(errors)
    }

};
```

ExpressJS `user.js` Route

```
route.post('/avatar', updateAvatar);
```

I can see some data when I use `req.files.file` (some of the data just encoding or decoding numbers, size and image jpg type) so how to upload this to mongodb using `mongoose` and `multer`

```
export const updateAvatar = async (req, res, next) => {

  upload.single('files');
  console.log(req);

  const { body } = req;
  console.log("in update avatar" + JSON.stringify(req.files.file.filename));
  // const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  //   destination: (req, file, cb) => {
  //     cb(null, 'uploads')
  //   },
  //   filename: (req, file, cb) => {
  //     cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  //   }
  // });

  // const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track with the React code to handle file uploads. However, your Express code needs a bit of adjustment to properly handle the uploaded file using Multer and store it in MongoDB using Mongoose.

This is an example of how you can modify your Express route to handle the file upload and store it in MongoDB using Multer and Mongoose:

```js
import multer from 'multer';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { YourMongooseModel } from '../models'; // Replace 'YourMongooseModel' with your actual Mongoose model

// Multer storage configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads'); // Destination folder where files will be saved
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname); // Set the file name to its original name
  },
});

// Initialize Multer upload with the configured storage
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Express route for handling file upload
export const updateAvatar = upload.single('files'), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No file uploaded' });
    }

    // Create a Mongoose document to save in the database
    const newFile = new YourMongooseModel({
      filename: req.file.originalname,
      path: req.file.path, // Path where the file is stored
      // Other properties you might want to add
    });

    // Save the file information in MongoDB
    await newFile.save();

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'File uploaded successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
  }
};

// then do this to your route
route.post('/avatar', upload.single('files'), updateAvatar);
```

Make sure to replace '**YourMongooseModel**' with your actual Mongoose model where you want to save the file information. This model should have fields like filename, path, and any other metadata you want to store for the uploaded file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciated. 

there's just issues in this line `export const updateAvatar = upload.single('files'), async (req, res, next) => {` 
there's an error `SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration` 

and probably this will be undefined `req.file.originalname,` because there's such a variable sent from front-end and I just tried and gives me undefined.

Comment: @Steven For the Missing initailzer you'll need to export, do something like this:

export const uploadAvatar = upload.single('files');

Then for this you req.file.originalname:

request.file gives the following stats, from which you would just need to pick request.file.originalname or request.file.filename to get the new filename created.

example of a file:

{ 
  fieldname: 'songUpload',
  originalname: '04. Stairway To Heaven - Led Zeppelin.mp3',
  ....more metadata
}

Comment: I tried upload with export in the rule of route.post  `route.post('/avatar', uploadAvatar, updateAvatar);` it returns 500 it doesn't even success

and it fails also in this I see th request it returns 405 
   `if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(405).json({ message: 'No file uploaded' });
    }` that If I didn't use `route.post('/avatar', uploadAvatar, updateAvatar);`

Comment: this's the function currently export `const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
export const uploadAvatar = upload.single('files');
// Express route for handling file upload
export const updateAvatar = async (req, res, next) => {   try {
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(405).json({ message: 'No file uploaded' });
    } etc... `

Comment: The issue relies in `upload.single('file')` once I call this function in `router.post()` the whole request fails and I blieve I'm using the right destination folder